# SQL Query- Table as invalid object

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query

```
 Select  
    temp1.domainname,
    temp1.employeeid,
    temp1.alletec_plantcode,
    temp1.name,
    temp1.alletec_customerengineer1name,
    temp1.alletec_cityname,
    temp1.alletec_regionname,
    temp1.alletec_ce1name,
    temp1.alletec_casecalltypename,
    count(temp1.alletec_ce1name) as TOTALMIFASSIGN ,
    (select count( MIF.alletec_ce1name) from temp1 where temp1.alletec_casecalltypename='aa') as CMMIFASSIGN

from (
    Select  
       User1.domainname,
       User1.employeeid,
       User1.alletec_plantcode,
       BU.name,
       MIF.alletec_customerengineer1name,
       MIF.alletec_cityname,
       MIF.alletec_regionname,
       MIF.alletec_ce1name,
       Incident.alletec_casecalltypename
    From 
       FilteredSystemUser As User1 Inner Join FilteredBusinessUnit As BU ON User1.businessunitid=BU.businessunitid
       Inner join Filteredalletec_mif As MIF ON MIF.alletec_ce1=User1.systemuserid
       Inner join FilteredIncident As Incident On Incident.alletec_serialnomif=MIF.alletec_mifid  
       where MIF.alletec_ce1name='Amit Chauhan' AND MIF.alletec_cityname='Gurgaon' and MIF.alletec_regionname='North' and Incident.statecodename='Resolved'
       group by User1.domainname,
         User1.employeeid,
         User1.alletec_plantcode,
         BU.name, 
         MIF.alletec_cityname,
         MIF.alletec_regionname,
         MIF.alletec_ce1name,
         MIF.alletec_customerengineer1name,
         Incident.alletec_casecalltypename
     ) As temp1
group by 
    temp1.domainname,
    temp1.employeeid,
    temp1.alletec_plantcode,
    temp1.name,
    temp1.alletec_customerengineer1name,
    temp1.alletec_cityname,
    temp1.alletec_regionname,
    temp1.alletec_ce1name,
    temp1.alletec_casecalltypename
```

The particular query above showing the temp1 as `Invalid Object` in the count query as i am require to place further filtration on it. Cant we use the above query in Aggregate function. Kindly suggest the an alternative to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to be that the table alias temp1 isn't available when the query processor tries to resolve it. One solution that should work would be to wrap the query in a common table expression (cte). I believe this will work.

Try this:

```
;with temp1 (
    domainname, employeeid,
    alletec_plantcode, name,
    alletec_customerengineer1name,
    alletec_cityname, alletec_regionname,
    alletec_ce1name, alletec_casecalltypename
    )
as (
    Select  
       User1.domainname,
         User1.employeeid,
         User1.alletec_plantcode,
         BU.name,
         MIF.alletec_customerengineer1name,
         MIF.alletec_cityname,
         MIF.alletec_regionname,
         MIF.alletec_ce1name,
         Incident.alletec_casecalltypename
    From 
       FilteredSystemUser As User1 Inner Join FilteredBusinessUnit As BU ON User1.businessunitid=BU.businessunitid
       Inner join Filteredalletec_mif As MIF ON MIF.alletec_ce1=User1.systemuserid
       Inner join FilteredIncident As Incident On Incident.alletec_serialnomif=MIF.alletec_mifid  
       where MIF.alletec_ce1name='Amit Chauhan' AND MIF.alletec_cityname='Gurgaon' and MIF.alletec_regionname='North' and Incident.statecodename='Resolved'
       group by User1.domainname,
         User1.employeeid,
         User1.alletec_plantcode,
         BU.name, 
         MIF.alletec_cityname,
         MIF.alletec_regionname,
         MIF.alletec_ce1name,
         MIF.alletec_customerengineer1name,
         Incident.alletec_casecalltypename
     ) 
Select
    temp1.domainname,
    temp1.employeeid,
    temp1.alletec_plantcode,
    temp1.name,
    temp1.alletec_customerengineer1name,
    temp1.alletec_cityname,
    temp1.alletec_regionname,
    temp1.alletec_ce1name,
    temp1.alletec_casecalltypename,
    (select count(temp1.alletec_ce1name) from temp1) as TOTALMIFASSIGN
from temp1
```

Comment: Actually, i am require to place further filtration on the temp1. Please check the query above. i have edited it that. thanks

Comment: @user3046812 You should be able to just add the line: `(select count( temp1.alletec_ce1name) from temp1 where temp1.alletec_casecalltypename='aa') as CMMIFASSIGN` to the end of my query.

Comment: hi. how can i put a rownumber in front of each row find in main query??

Comment: @user3046812 It depends on what database system you are using. By the way, instead of asking follow up questions in comments, it's better to post a new question so that more people are given the chance to answer. Anyway, for MS SQL you can get row numbers by adding this to the select part: `rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY employeeid)`